# Passar array de um checkbox como parâmetro

Tags: php, array, checkbox

Estou desenvolvendo em PHP um sistema básico, e na tela inicial estou listando todos os usuários cadastrados. Para cada user, tenho um checkbox que recebe o valor do código do usuário. Eu gostaria que verificassem se o checkbox está correto e como eu faria para mandar o array para outra página que realiza, por exemplo, a exclusão dos usuários selecionados? Isto através do clique em um botão...

```
//Botões
<div class="span4" style="margin-left: 0;width:470px;text-align: right;">
            <a href="cadastroUsuario.php"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Novo Usuário</button></a>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-th-list icon-white"></i> Opções</a>
              <a class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="text-align: left;">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> Visualizar Tudo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar Usuário</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Apagar Usuário</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-check"></i> Ativar Usuário</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> Desativar Usuário</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

//Tabela com os dados dos usuários
<table width="100%" border="0" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
              <tr>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">#</th>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">Codigo</th>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">Empresa</th>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">Cidade</th>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">UF</th>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">Telefone</th>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">CPF/CPNJ</th>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">E-Mail</th>
                <th nowrap="nowrap">Status</th>
                <th colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap">Ações</th>
              </tr>
            <?php
                if ($resultadoBusca != null){

                    foreach($resultadoBusca as $escrever){
//checkbox recebedo cod_user                            
echo "<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=\"check_idUser[]\" value=\"".$escrever['cod_user']."\"></td>
                        <td>" . $escrever['cod_votoran'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . utf8_encode($escrever['empresa_user']) . "</td>
                        <td>" . utf8_encode($escrever['cidade_user']) . "</td>
                        <td>" . $escrever['estado_user'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $escrever['fone_user'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $escrever['cpfcnpj_user'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $escrever['email_user'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $escrever['status_user'] . "</td>
                        <td>";
                        echo "<a href=\"visualizarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"><i class=\"icon-eye-open\" title=\"Visualizar Todos os Dados do  Usuário!\"></i></a>";
                        if($escrever['status_user']=='ativo'|| $escrever['status_user']=='Ativo')
                        {
                            echo "<a href=\"desativarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"> <i class=\"icon-ban-circle\" title=\"Desativar Usuário!\"></i></a>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<a href=\"ativarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"> <i class=\"icon-check\" title=\"Ativar Usuário!\"></i></a>";
                        }
                        echo "<a href=\"editarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"> <i class=\"icon-edit\" title=\"Editar Usuário!\"></i></a>";
                        echo "<a href=\"excluirUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"> <i class=\"icon-remove\" title=\"Remover Usuário!\"></i></a></td>
                                            </tr>";
                    }  
                                        }else{
                    echo '<table style="width:100%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(242, 222, 222);"><div align="center"><strong><tr><td>Desculpe! Não Existe Nenhum Usuário Cadastrado</td></tr></strong></div></table>';
                }
            echo "</table>";
            ?>
```

[image: Tabela com usuários sendo listada na página]

Comment: Vai ter de usar AJAX... sabe como fazer?

Comment: Não sei. Estou começando a desenvolver em PHP e é uma de minhas primeiras experiências ;s

Comment: Ok. Quer usar JavaScript puro ou uma biblioteca como MooTools ou jQuery?

Comment: Cara, eu não tenho idéia, pois nunca usei nenhum destes que vocês estão falando ;s

Comment: Sem saber isso fica dificil responder... outra pergunta: quando essa checkbox é clicada o que quer que aconteça`fica na mesma página mas esse usuário desaparece, fica meio transparente, ou outro? Tem uma base de dados já com os usuários?

Comment: Sim, tenho uma base montada. E na tela inicial através desta tabela estão sendo listados todos os usuários. Ao lado de cada um é colocada esta checkbox, porém ela não faz nada além de receber o valor do cod_user. Se clicar nela não acontece nada. E na verdade pergunto aqui, por que o pessoal sempre ajuda e acredito que alguém deve ter um norte para me ajudar.

Comment: Rodrigo eu vou dar-lhe uma resposta. Pode responder primeiro à pergunta/comentário anterior: quando essa checkbox é clicada o que quer que aconteça?

Comment: Pela introdução da pergunta @Sergio, ele quer usar as `checkbox` marcar um ou mais utilizadores e ao clicar num botão fazer um _post_ para um ficheiro onde esses utilizadores vão ser removidos do sistema. Em termos de UI, em sucesso deveriam ser removidos da listagem. :) _(mas isto é a minha interpretação do pretendido)_

Comment: Não acontece nada ainda, como já havia dito. Editei o post e coloquei uma imagem da página para verificar como está.

Comment: Rodrigo a minha pergunta é mais do tipo: qual é o seu desejo para eu responder como fazer...

Comment: @Zuul pois, daí a minha pergunta em cima "esse usuário desaparece, fica meio transparente, ou outro?" para a afinar a resposta :) (aha, vi agora a imagem na resposta, ficou melhor)

Comment: Eu quero o seguinte: Bem como na imagem, selecionar os usuários que desejo apagar, e clicar no botão destacado 'APAGAR USUÁRIO' para remover todos os usuários selecionados. Até onde pesquisei, teria de guardar em um array os valores selecionados (não sei como) e após mandar para uma página em específica que pega o array e faz o SQL para remoção dos mesmos do BD.

Comment: Rodrigo podes colocar aqui o HTML desse menu onde clicas "Apagar Usuário"?

Comment: Editei no código, é a primeira parte dele. Da uma olhada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividindo o problema em partes os passos que tem de fazer são:

1. Criar um event handler para iniciar uma ação quando carregar em "Apagar tudo"
2. Verificar quais os utilizadores escolhidos para serem removidos
3. Enviar para o PHP via AJAX e quando a confirmação vier, então apagar no HTML
4. Apagar na base de dados (lado do servidor / PHP)
5. Apagar os utilizadores (de volta ao lado do cliente / JavaScript)

#### Agora por passos:

### #1

```
$('i.icon-trash').closest('li').click(fnApagar);
```

Este código vai procurar um `li` que tem dentro `i.icon-trash` e chamar a função `fnApagar()` quando esse `li` for clicado.

### #2

Aqui tens de procurar na tabela quais os utilizadores escolhidos. Seria bom se essa tabela tivesse uma ID para não haver confusões caso haja mais que uma tabela na página.

```
var paraRemover = $('table tr input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){ 
    return {
        cod_votoran: this.value, 
        tr: $(this).closest('tr')[0]
    }
});
```

Nesta linha de código em cima vou procurar os utilizadores escolhidos e guardar 2 coisas. O código que preciso para a base de dados, e a linha da tabela para mais tarde apagar.

### #3

**Ajax!** Ajax é a maneira que o browser tem para comunicar com o servidor e enviar e receber dados sem ter de carregar a página toda de novo.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "endereco.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: {codigos: [array com os códigos a remover]},
    success: function(resposta){
      // esta função é corrida quando a resposta volta do servidor
      // if (resposta == true) apagar esse(s) usuário(s)
    }
});
```

### #4

Os dados enviados para o servidor podem ser capturados pelo `$_POST`. Aí tem de percorrer essa array e fazer a remoção na base de dados. Em detalhe não posso responder pois fata informação na pergunta (pode fazer uma pergunta nova se ficar enrascado aqui).

Exemplo:

```
$usuarios_a_apagar = $_POST['codigos'];
$sql = implode(', ', $usuarios_a_apagar ); // para ficar com "cod1, cod2, etc"
```

Depois na query à base de dados pode usar:

```
"DELETE FROM clientes WHERE ID IN ($sql)"
```

Depois só falta enviar de volta para o lado do cliente a confirmação:

```
    if ($excluir == 2) echo '[true, "Usuário Excluí­do com Sucesso"]';
    elseif ($excluir == 0) echo '[false, "Houve um erro ao excluir usuário, talvez já tenha sido excluí­do anteriormente!"]';
    else echo '[false, "O Sistema apresentou algum erro, fale com o administrador!"]';
```

### #5

Com a resposta do servidor (assumindo que retorna `true`) temos então que apagar essas linhas da tabela. Como já as tinhamos guardado podemos fazer assim:

```
paraRemover.each(function(){ this.tr.remove(); });
```

### O código (JS) completo:

```
$('i.icon-trash').closest('li').click(fnApagar);

function fnApagar() {
    var paraRemover = $('table tr input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return {
            cod_votoran: this.value,
            tr: $(this).closest('tr')[0]
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "endereco.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            codigos: paraRemover.map(function(){ return this.cod_votoran; }).get()
        },
        success: function (resposta) {
             if (resposta[0]) paraRemover.each(function(){
                this.tr.remove();
            }); 
            alert(resposta[1]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: tenho outra pergunta relacionada a tudo que fizemos aqui. Estou fazendo a mesma coisa agora para ativar vários usuários. Tudo já funcionando. Minha única dúvida é a seguinte: aonde tenho `this.tr[0].remove();` ele remove a linha da tabela,porém, quando ativo um usuário gostaria apenas que mudasse o campo `Status` para: `Inativo` e cor `Vermelho`. Teria como?

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto sim, pode fazer isso com classes. Tipo `this.tr[0].classList.add('inativo');` ou com jQuery `$(this.tr[0]).addClass('inativo');`

Comment: Testando direto aqui [http://jsfiddle.net/ya1ytv3k/ ] tentei das duas formas e não acontece nada

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto um exemplo para marcar a linha vermelha: http://jsfiddle.net/ya1ytv3k/7/ não esqueça a classe CSS. Faca nova pergunta se tiver problema que vamos ajudar.

Comment: Nâo é bem isso. Mas vou fazer outra pergunta. :D